# Bootstrap 4 : div with Equal height with color fill and gutter in between

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve a bootstrap 4 layout for which I have added screenshot. I read most of the other stack overflow post, but not getting the solution

1. The `.container-fluid` layout is having the grey fill color, which is by using my custom class `.bg-grey`.
2. According to the design , the body is in center, so I added `.container` class to wrap the columns.
3. `.col-8` has `.bg-white` and `.col-4` has `.bg-dark` classes with them. And I had to make it off same height.
4. There is a gutter(space) in between them.

**Problem Facing**

1. Getting an extra margin on right, so the design is not properly centered in between.

**Design trying to achieve**

[image: bootstrap 4 Layout : trying to achieve]

So the problem in my solution is, I am getting an extra margin on the right. I have tried two cases for which I have the code.

**CASE 1:**

Tried a lot with below code and was not able to achieve the  solution.

1. If I add margin to `col-8`, second div `.col-4` comes down as the total width increases.
2. If I add `.bg-white` and `.bg-dark` to a new child the size of the fill color changes.
3. To the newly created div inside, I have added `.h-100` class, but even this didn't work

[image: No gutter or no equal height]

```html
<div class="col-sm-8  ">
  <div class="content px-4 py-2 bg-white h-100">
    <h3 class="heading03">Life at </h3>
    <h2 class="heading02">.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
    </p>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 ">
  <div class=" content px-4 py-2 bg-black white-text h-100">
    <h5 class="heading05">Latest at </h5>
    <h4 class="heading04 text-muted">Top 10 </h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa...
    </p>
    <h5 class="heading05">Latest at </h5>
    <h4 class="heading04 text-muted">Top 10 </h4>
    <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa...
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CASE 2:** This layout I tried from the below example from bootstrap website.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/product/

This is how it looks with current code. The margins are not equal

1. Tried removing `. mr-md-3` from `.col-4`. It didn't help

[image: design 2]

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid bg-grey pb-5 ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- second part -->


      <div class="row pt-5">

        <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 ">

          <div class="col-8 bg-white mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="my-3 py-3">
              <h3 class="heading03">Life </h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
                tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-4 bg-dark mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-white overflow-hidden">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="my-3 p-3">
                <h2 class="display-5"> headline</h2>
                <p class="lead">subheading.</p>
              </div>

            </div>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're saying the right margin is smaller due to the scrollbar?

Comment: If I have no scroll in the page, it still comes in right.

Comment: So what is the question then, full height without scroll? If no scrolling, then what will happen if content height exceeds the viewport height?

Comment: Qurstion: The 2 divs (col-8, col-4) are not alligned in center to the parent div.      As in, when we do margin: 0 auto, to the child  div, it align itself in to center. But it doesn't happen here.

Comment: But again, aside from the scrollbar they are centered. Please create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The 2 snippets you've posted aren't properly structured

Comment: I do not understand whether you want to achieve the first img or the second. Could you explain which one you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is something like this. (find attached the snippet).

The bootstrap class`h-100` which makes the height of the div 100%, sets the height of the two child `col`s of your `row` to be of same height. You can find that [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/).

When it is same height, everything is working fine. The margin and the gutter. Please check the snippet below.

I've just added background color to differentiate the changes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid bg-danger pb-5 ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row pt-5">              
            
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="content px-4 py-2 bg-white h-100">
                    <h3 class="heading03">Life at </h3>
                    <h2 class="heading02">We plan to be among them.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                        massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
                        quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
                        rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend
                        tellus.
                    </p>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class=" content px-4 py-2 bg-dark text-white h-100">
                    <h5 class="heading05">Latest at </h5>
                    <h4 class="heading04 text-muted">Top 10  </h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                        massa...
                    </p>
                    <h5 class="heading05">Latest at </h5>
                    <h4 class="heading04 text-muted">Top 10  </h4>
                    <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                        massa...
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is your text laid out in the same markup, one with and one without background color so you can see the spacing visually.

I've justified the text so you can see the gutters represented by the default BS padding applied to columns

It seems to me that BS does a good job centering things by default.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid bg-danger">
  <div class="p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 bg-info">
        <h3 class="heading03">Life</h3>
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-white">
        <h2 class="display-5"> headline</h2>
        <p class="lead">subheading.</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <h3 class="heading03">Life</h3>
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <h2 class="display-5"> headline</h2>
        <p class="lead">subheading.</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want different background colors with a visual "break" don't mess with the column padding and margins but wrap their contents in divs and play with the padding and margins there

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid bg-danger">
  <div class="p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 bg-info">
        <div class="mr-1 bg-warning">
          <h3 class="heading03">Life</h3>
          <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-white">
        <div class="ml-1 bg-warning">
        <h2 class="display-5"> headline</h2>
        <p class="lead">subheading.</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="mr-1">
          <h3 class="heading03">Life</h3>
          <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-white">
        <div class="ml-1">
        <h2 class="display-5"> headline</h2>
        <p class="lead">subheading.</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this will help me(second) snippet.

Comment: Glad to help clarify.  My main thought was to allow you to visualize Bootstrap padding and margins.  Once you choose to use the their Grid system I've found it's best to work within the framework not to mess with their scaffolding so to speak.

Comment: Currently I am somewhat using above code. Is it a good practice to add padding inside .cool classes

Comment: I have found that using the padding classes directly on `col` class to be minimally invasive. But they are defined with their own padding and I usually opt to leave their framework intact.  I usually wrap my content and apply any styling to the wrapper.